# How to loop a try catch statement?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

How do you loop a try/catch statement? I'm making a program that is reading in a file using a Scanner and it's reading it from the keyboard. So what I want is if the file does not exist, the program will say "This file does not exist please try again." then have the user type in a different file name. I have tried a couple different ways to try an do this but, all of my attempts end up with the program crashing.

Here is what I have

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File(in.next());
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File does not exist please try again. ");
    }
```

Comment: Well, you need to actually use a `for` or `while` (or others - in before pedants ;-) in order to loop.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to retry after a failure, you need to put that code inside a loop; e.g. something like this:

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    try {
        ...
        done = true;
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

(A do-while is a slightly more elegant solution.)

However, it is BAD PRACTICE to catch `Exception` in this context.  It will catch not only the exceptions that you are expecting to happen (e.g. `IOException`), but also unexpected ones, like `NullPointerException` and so on that are symptoms of a bug in your program.

Best practice is to catch the exceptions that you are expecting (and can handle), and allow any others to propagate.  In your particular case, catching `FileNotFoundException` is sufficient.  (That is what the `Scanner(File)` constructor declares.)  If you weren't using a `Scanner` for your input, you might need to catch `IOException` instead.

---

I must correct a serious mistake in the top-voted answer.

```
do {
    ....
} while (!file.exists());
```

This is incorrect because testing that the file exists is not sufficient:

- the file might exist but the user doesn't have permission to read it,
- the file might exist but be a directory,
- the file might exist but be unopenable due to hard disc error, or similar
- the file might be deleted/unlinked/renamed between the `exists()` test succeeding and the subsequent attempt to open it.

Note that:

1. `File.exists()` ONLY tests that a file system object exists with the specified path, not that it is actually a file, or that the user has read or write access to it.
2. There is no way to test if an I/O operation is *going to* fail due to an hard disc errors, network drive errors and so on.
3. There is no solution to the open vs deleted/unlinked/renamed race condition.  While it is rare in normal usage, this kind of bug *can be targeted* if the file in question is security critical.

The correct approach is to simply attempt to open the file, and catch and handle the `IOException` if it happens.  It is simpler and more robust, and probably faster.  And for those who would say that exceptions should not be used for "normal flow control", this *isn't* normal flow control ...

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a try catch block, try a `do while` loop checking if the file exists.

```
do {

} while ( !file.exists() );
```

This method is in `java.io.File`

Comment: +1 for using `file.exists()`. Just to add, it would be good to put the second `Scanner` statement outside this loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the positive comments, feel free to suggest edits so that the user can use this correctly.

Comment: -1 - for using `file.exists()`.  You have only tested for one of possibly many reasons while the supplied file might fail to open.  Furthermore you cannot test for all of the possibilities, so it is a bad idea to even try.  This is really the wrong approach.  The right approach is to *try to open* the file and catch the exception.

Comment: @StephenC you stated in your own answer that catching `Exception` is a bad practice. So what exceptions, specifically, should the OP catch instead of checking `file.exists()`? Apart from `FileNotFoundException`, which I assume to be adequately mitigated by using `file.exists`.

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple for him, as he originally stated he was just learning Java.

Comment: @squiguy - 1) My comment doesn't say he needs to handle `Exception`.  It says the exception.  Specifically, he needs to handle `IOException`. The compiler will tell him this. 2) You don't make life simple for people by suggesting a solution that is incorrect. And your solution is (I have to say) incorrect, for the reasons that I have listed in my Answer. (For a start, it won't compile unless you catch or declare the checked exceptions.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap it in a loop:

```
while(...){

    try{

    } catch(Exception e) {

    }

}
```

However, catching **every** exception and just assuming that it is due to the file not existing is probably not the best way of going about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
boolean success = false;

while (!success)
{
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File(in.next());
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(file);
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File does not exist please try again. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists using the API.

```
String filename = "";

while(!(new File(filename)).exists())
{
    if(!filename.equals("")) System.out.println("This file does not exist.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    filename = new String(in.next();        
}
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner scan =  new Scanner(file);
```