# Why is the boolean in the "try" part of a "Try/Catch" method?

Tags: java, boolean, try-catch

I'm using a `Scanner` to get input from a user, but I want to check if it's an integer or not. So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233489/how-to-loop-a-try-catch-statement). The thing is, I don't understand why in this solution `done = true` is in the `try` part.

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    try {
        ...
        done = true;
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

If I were to have my input in the `try`, like this:

```
try {
  input = sc.nextInt();
  done = true;
}
```

And if the input is not an `int` and goes into the `catch` part, why would it re-do the loop if the `boolean` has already been changed, even if it there isn't a `break` or `continue` right after it?

Also, I would've gone with a `throw new` like in  [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924749/try-catch-for-scanner), but it hasn't been officially explained to me yet, so I'm not allowed to use it.

Another thing, can it only be done with a `do-while` like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288109/looping-around-a-try-catch)?
In the last link, why does it say `scanner.next();` in the `catch` and not `input = scanner.nextInt();`? Or is that the same?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid** asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `input = sc.nextInt();` throws an exception for not being an int, it will instantly jump to the catch. This means the line `done = true;` isn't run. By having it inside the try the loop will only be exited when the user enters a valid int.

Answer (score 3):

*And if the input is not an int and goes into the catch part,*

If the user enters an input that is not an `int` **it will** then go into the catch part **and** it will **not** set `done = true;` (because it has gone into the catch the following statements in the `try` - after the `Exception` **do not** execute).

Comment: Thank you, kindly as well, mate. :3

Answer (score 2):

Simple: the outer loop will repeat to ask for user input **until** the `done` variable indicates: "now we have received correct input".

In other words: the *catch* is required when the input isn't as expected; but when that line `done=true` is reached - all is fine; and the loop can "end".

That is all there is to this.

Comment: Thank very much. :3

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the quick upvote. I appreciate newbies that quickly show their feedback to all people giving reasonable answers. That is a possible I try to follow myself to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing complicated logic with `while`, I would recommend using `hasNextInt()` method of Scanner class, [here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) the javadoc:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt()
>   method.

So, you can call this method inside `if` and proceed further if it returns true;

Comment: Well, we haven't seen that one, so I wouldn't be allowed to use it. Besides, I've never used it before anyway and I know more about `while` than I do about `hasNextInt()`, but still, appreciate the help. Upvoteronis. :3